# How does this regex code work (positive lookahead)?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I entered the following regex:

`(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@#$%]).{8,20}`

And give the following input string for pattern search:

`A00123456789123456789gj673%`

It gave me the matched output as:

`A0012345678912345678`

Can you explain me why it's giving me output when the order of characters entered in input string doesn't matched the order in which regex pattern is entered?

If possible, plz explain me how this works sequentially.

Comment: A complete description of how this regex works can be found here: https://regex101.com/r/f3VwEs/1

Comment: Please avoid language spamming.

Comment: @Turing85: You have editing privileges.  Feel free to remove the tags that don't pertain.  It's a new contributor; I doubt very much they understand what you mean by "language spamming."

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is being partially matched. If you want to prevent it's matching, you can do it by adding ^ and $ to the begin and end of your pattern.

^: asserts position at start of a line

$: asserts position at the end of a line

The final pattern would be like:

```
(?=^[a-z]*[A-Z]*[0-9]*[@#$%]*$)(?=(.{8,20}))
```

Comment: OP asked for an explanation, not a modification. This does not answer the question.

Comment: @Turing85 Ok i'll explain it

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it still matches for string length between 8 and 20 with any order , like if entered input string ``A012345gj673%``, it still matches. Shouldn't it be in order like after encountering a [a-z] character (eg. after encountering ```g`` or `j`` in above input string) next it must search for a [A-Z] character? The only characters after that are ``6``, ``7``, ``3`` and ``%``, there is no capital letter character.

Comment: @mp3001 got a match for youi. and edited the answer. Good luck